# how to index a mongodb similar mongodb queries with only different sort values

Tags: mongodb

For example, if I have the following query:

```
db.things.find({
  param1: value1,
  param2: value2,
  param3: value3
}).sort({
  sortvalue1: -1
})
```

These params are always the same, but the `sortvalue1` has many different possibilities (say, 5). What's the best way to index?

```
{
  param1: -1,
  param2: -1,
  param3: -1,
  sortvalue1: -1
}
```

for each `sortvalue`, or a single, large, compound index with all the sort indexes?

```
{
  param1: -1,
  param2: -1,
  param3: -1,
  sortvalue1: -1,
  sortvalue2: -1,
  sortvalue3: -1,
  sortvalue4: -1,
  sortvalue5: -1
}
```

Why?

Comment: Only an `explain` can answer this tbh

Comment: Unfortunately, single index won't work in this case. So, the only way is to use multiple indexes.

Comment: i'm not doubting you, but do you have a source?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny might be right here but an explain would have to do it. You can see how MongoDB is complicated when it comes to sorting here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results whereby it cannot sort on the `b` example even though it is in index, however you are using the prefix of the compound index at all times unlike that example so I am not totally sure.

Comment: yes. sure, explain will tell me what does and doesn't work, but i want to know why so i don't have to test every index and query. maybe ill ask on the mailing list or something.

Comment: There are any number of reasons, it can even come down to the selectivity of the data and its position in the index (i.e. 3rd field in the index as opposed to 2nd) basically that page will tell you, basically, what indexes MongoDB will look for, if you plan your indexes around that it should give off only a couple of combinations to try, the mailing list (being one of the ones who answer there too) will most likely give you the exact same answer